# Building android app with command prompt

Tags: android, build, sdk, path, gradlew

i am trying to build my first training application for android using only `sdk tools`. I am using this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

I am in my project folder which was generated with android create project command.I am using windows 8.1 64 bits.
Unfortunately when i am trying to run `gradlew.bat assembleDebug` i an got error:

```
'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal command or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

I don't know what is going on. I add platform-tools and tools to my path. I would be grateful for help!

When i am using gradle -v i am getting information about gradle. Byt gradlew.bat is not working.

Comment: The error says ´gradlaw.bat´. Are you sure you didn't just misspelled the command?

Comment: What is `gradlaw.bat` btw?

Comment: @user3402584 Did you try my answer

Comment: yea, i add %SystemRoot%\system32;  to the beginning of my PATH. I put my project to tools and platform tools and still not working when i am using this command while being inside the project. I am using win 8.1 64 bits if that helps.

Comment: @user3402584 Did you add the JDK too?

Comment: when i am using javac and java in cmd it works. Where gradlew is located btw? Beacuse it looks like i am having problems with paths.

Comment: maybe i am not having gradle at all? how to check it ?

Comment: @user3402584 Take a look -> http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle-is-not-recognized-internal-or-external-command

Comment: i did everything. when i use gradle -v i got info. But gradlew.bat is still not working

Answer (score 2):

Find the directory where **gradlew.bat** present and add it your the Environment path.

> I found gradlew in he below path and it works!!!!
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper\

Comment: It's useful your answer. For example if you want to distribute beta apps with [Fabric.io](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html) throught Gradle, you need `gradlew` using line commands: `gradlew assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease`

Answer (score 1):

Just do this, this solved my problem before.

> Open Control Panel
>
> Go to System → Environment Variables
>
> In PATH add the following entry at the beginning: `%SystemRoot%\system32`;

Comment: But i still have problem , i m not able to build its says * What went wrong:
Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'admin'. any leads?